# How do I build a new column in pandas using the result of matching a string in column A on a regex pattern from column B?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Tried the code below and I am getting `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.`

```
df['match'] = df['my_string'].str.fullmatch(df['my_pattern'])
```

The comparison needs to be done row by row as the regex pattern is different on every row.

Result should look like:

| my_string | my_pattern | match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | `\d{4}` | True |
| AB123456 | `AB\d{6,7}` | True |
| AB123 | `AB\d{8}` | False |

Couldn't find anything that solves this. Seems so trivial. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `df['match'] = df.apply(lambda r: bool(re.fullmatch(r['my_pattern'], r['my_string'])), axis=1)` work?

Comment: Getting `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 18, placement implies 1`. This is another error I've been getting when using df.apply

Comment: Then you should provide a reproducible example. It works with `df = pd.DataFrame({'my_string':['1234','AB123456', 'AB123'],'my_pattern':[r'\d{4}',r'AB\d{6,7}',r'AB\d{8}']})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_string':['1234','AB123456', 'AB123'],'my_pattern':[r'\d{4}',r'AB\d{6,7}',r'AB\d{8}']})
>>> df.apply(lambda r: bool(re.fullmatch(r['my_pattern'], r['my_string'])), axis=1)
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Here, we iterate over the rows with `.apply` and `axis=1`, and use the `re` library's `fullmatch` method to check if the pattern from Column `my_pattern` fully matches the value in the corresponding cell in Column `my_string`.